# PHP simple HTML DOM tag overlapping

Tags: php, html, dom

I've got a page i want to parse that has overlapping tags like this

```
 <div>
  <p>
   <strong>
    <span>sometext</span>
     <div> <- this tag is misplaced
   </strong>
  </p>
       <- and should be here
     </div>
```

The problem is there're more p tags to be parsed, but the parser thinks that it reached the end.

I need it to be parsed in the way i can access each p separately

```
$ar_w = $ar->find('div[itemprop=ar] p');
    foreach ($ar_w as $para) {
        //something
    }
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

- You cannot put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` (but since the end tag for `<p>` is optional, the `<div>` will implicitly end it and then the `</p>` will be ignored because there is no matching `<p>`).
- You cannot put a `<div>` or inside a `<strong>`
- You cannot have a `<div>` start tag without a matching end tag

If you want to recover from the HTML errors in a particular, non-standard way, you'll need to write a custom parser. Pre-built ones tend to follow the HTML rules.